# navigationItem titleView - Logo too big for iPhone6+

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm adding a logo in the navigation bar.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"00-logo"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

It looks okay with iPhone4S, iPhone5S, iPhone6 but in iPhone6+ it's a little bit too big, so there are some pixels below the nav bar.

I tried with:

```
[self.navigationItem.titleView sizeToFit];
```

But still doesn't work.

The images I'm using for the logo are:

- 00-logo@2x.png - 203x72.
- 00-logo@3x.png - 393x138.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 3x image has the wrong dimensions compared to the 2x image.

Remember, if the 1x image is w x h pixels, the 2x image must be 2w x 2h pixels and the 3x image must be 3w x 3h pixels.

Given your 2x image of 203 x 72, your 3x image must be 304.5 x 108 pixels, not 393 x 138.

Note that 2x images should have even widths and heights.